# Visualization of CDSE WMS tiles using Folium

Tags: wms, layers, sentinel-2, folium, cdse

Using the Copernicus Data Space Ecosystem dashboard I created a New Configuration that I am able to visualize on Folium using Python.

How can I specify an absolute timestamp? I want to visualize a specific date that can be selected programatically and not the most recent one. Here is my code:

```
m = folium.Map()
url = "https://sh.dataspace.copernicus.eu/ogc/wms/d9b6faf8-52af-...9"
w = folium.raster_layers.WmsTileLayer(url=url,
                                      name="Natural color",
                                      styles="RGB",
                                      fmt="image/png",
                                      transparent=True,
                                      layers="NATURAL-COLOR",
                                      overlay=True)
w.add_to(m)
m
```

[image]

Comment: How does the WMS GetCapabilities response describe the time dimension?

Comment: @nmtoken How can I check that? I know that plugins.TimestampedWmsTileLayers recognises the time dimension and that the time must be described according to TIME=2020-09-18T00:00:00.0Z/2020-09-19T00:00:00.0Z

Comment: `https://sh.dataspace.copernicus.eu/ogc/wms/d9b6faf8-52af-...9?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities&`

Comment: <Dimension name="time" units="ISO8601"/>
<Extent name="time" default="2023-09-05">1984-03-01/2023-09-05/P1D</Extent>

Comment: So, it was quite simple... I just added time="2020-09-23". Now I notice that even if there is no imagery for a certain day, the service always provide an image from a close day. How can I output the correct date that correspond to the image that I am visualising?

Comment: so adding time="1984-03-01" to your parameters should work, P1D tells you that the period resolution is one day

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148325/discussion-between-just-4n0th3r-pr0gr4mm3r-and-nmtoken).

Comment: Try a GetFeatureInfo request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the name of the dimension (as described in the GetCapabilities response) to the list of parameters.

So if the GetCapabilities response gives:

```
<Dimension name="time" units="ISO8601"/>
<Extent name="time" default="2023-09-05">1984-03-01/2023-09-05/P1D</Extent>
```

then use a time string in the format YYYY-MM-DD, like `time="1984-03-01"`

`P1D` tells you that the time period resolution is one day.